# FPDF saving and viewing saved PDFs

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a form that is converted into a PDF using FPDF

i am looking for a way to store the PDFs in a folder on the site and have a page where it displays them all in a list by $name.

I did try google around but found nothing.

my FPDF Code:

```
<?php
//set the question values
$questions     = array(
'name' => "Name: ",
'email' => "Email: ",
'fax' => "Fax Number: ",
'privateaddress' => "Address (Private): ",
'companyaddress' => "Address (Company): ",
'contactprivate' => "Contact Number (Private): ",
'contactcompany' => "Contact Number (Company): ",
'Q1' => "Question 1: ",
'Q2' => "Question 2: ",
'Q3' => "Question 3: ",
'Q4' => "Question 4: ",
'Q5' => "Question 5: ",
'Q6' => "Question 6: ",
'Q7' => "Question 7: ",
'Q8' => "Question 8: ",
'Q9' => "Question 9: ",
'Q10' => "Question 10: ",
'Q11' => "Question 11: ",

);
 //set the question answers
$name          = $_POST['name'];
$email         = $_POST['email'];
$fax           = $_POST['fax'];
$privateaddress= $_POST['privateaddress'];
$companyaddress= $_POST['companyaddress'];
$contactprivate= $_POST['contactprivate'];
$contactcompany= $_POST['contactcompany'];
$question1= $_POST['Q1'];
$question2= $_POST['Q2'];
$question3= $_POST['Q3'];
$question4= $_POST['Q4'];
$question5= $_POST['Q5'];
$question6= $_POST['Q6'];
$question7= $_POST['Q7'];
$question8= $_POST['Q8'];
$question9= $_POST['Q9'];
$question10= $_POST['Q10'];
$question11= $_POST['Q11'];
//set the question names
$Name  = $questions['name'];
$Email  = $questions['email'];
$Fax  = $questions['fax'];
$Privateaddress  = $questions['privateaddress'];
$Companyaddress  = $questions['companyaddress'];
$Contactprivate  = $questions['contactprivate'];
$Contactcompany  = $questions['contactcompany'];
$q1  = $questions['Q1'];
$q2  = $questions['Q2'];
$q3  = $questions['Q3'];
$q4  = $questions['Q4'];
$q5  = $questions['Q5'];
$q6  = $questions['Q6'];
$q7  = $questions['Q7'];
$q8  = $questions['Q8'];
$q9  = $questions['Q9'];
$q10  = $questions['Q10'];
$q11  = $questions['Q11'];

require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('images/logo.png', 10, 6, 30);

    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);

    $this->Cell(50);


    $this->Cell(90, 10, 'Claim Form', 'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{

    $this->SetY(-15);

    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);

    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
}
}


$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
//insert questions and answers
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $Name, $name));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $Email, $email));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $Fax, $fax));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $Privateaddress, $privateaddress));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $Contactprivate, $contactprivate));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $Companyaddress, $ccompanyaddress));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $Contactcompany, $contactcompany));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q1, $question1));

$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q2, $question2));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q3, $question3));

$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q4, $question4));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q5, $question5));

$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q6, $question6));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q7, $question7));

$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q8, $question8));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q9, $question9));

$pdf->MultiCell(50,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q10, $question10));

$pdf->MultiCell(150,10,sprintf("%s %s", $q11, $question11));
//display pdf
$fileName = 'New Claim By:' . $_POST['name'] . '.pdf';
$pdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: @SebastienD code added sir

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the code you provided does give you a pdf document, but instead of saving it on the server, it shows it in the browser. 
Please also note, that i highly suggest that you look into **properly escaping** the data you are retreiving from the `$_POST` variable, because your current code might be vounerable to any number of injection attacks, for example modifying the folder where documents are stored by adding ../../foldername/ to the filename input or even worse (depending if you are also storing that data to database,...).

from the documentation of FPDF, you can find the parameters to pass to the `$pdf->Output()` method, to save the file to the hard drive instead of serving it to the browser. So you should change that line to:
`$pdf->Output('F', $fileName);`

> Output
>
> Description Send the document to a given destination: browser, file or
>   string. In the case of a browser, the PDF viewer may be used or a
>   download may be forced. The method first calls Close() if necessary to
>   terminate the document. Parameters
>
> dest
>       Destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:
>
> ```
>     I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
>     D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
>     F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
>     S: return the document as a string.
>
> The default value is I.  name
> The name of the file. It is ignored in case of destination S.
> The default value is doc.pdf.string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
> ```

and then you would have another script to list the files in the directory by using php's `scandir` function. more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)
that is just one of the simpler options, there are many others.